# problem with import of sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, import

I have a prepolutated sqlite database, which I include as a resource in my app, because it would take too long to fill the database at startup. I created the prepopulated database with core data, so everything should be fine.
On a iphone 4 with iOS 4.2.1 this is the case, however when I test the exact same code on an iPhone 3GS, also running iOS 4.2.1, the database is copied to the documents folder, but there is never a result when I fetch for something in the database. Is the database layout on an iPhone 3GS different from the layout on an iPhone 4 (even if they have the same iOS version running) ?
Can someone explain me the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:&error];
```

into

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:&error];
```

Seems strange to me but it works now...